# Visualforce tab to track order details

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension

To capture all the order details I built a VF page with an extension to get all the orders details for the current user. Following is the way I tried...

```
public with sharing class Order_Extention{
    public Order_Extention(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Order__c.id');
    }
}
```

I get a blank VF page, but it works if I try https://xxx.cs11.visual.force.com/apex/OrderTracking?id=xxxxxx

How should I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need `Order__c` in the URL parameter? Try top do it without: `getParameters().get('id');`

Comment: Yes I tried that too. But when I load the VF page, this link shows up... cs11.visual.force.com/apex/OrderTracking?sfdc.tabName=01rZ0000000DIi0

Comment: how can I append "?id=xxxxx" to a vf tab ?

Comment: Got it now. I don't think you can pass parameters to the visualforce tab, I can't even see some useful usecases for it, sorry. But what I can imagine is that you will need some user input on the visualforce page (order-Id or name) to be able to select an order.

Comment: Ok. Got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need Order__c in the URL parameter? Try without it: `getParameters().get('id');`

The possible solution I can imagine is that you will need some user input on the visualforce page (order-Id or name) to be able to select an order.